# Consider the DSA digital signature scheme. Does the intercepted message m||s||r contain all information about the signer’s private key?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, dsa

Consider the DSA digital signature scheme.
Does the intercepted message m||s||r contain all information about the signer’s private key? Please justify your answer carefully.

Please note that the equation $a = αx \mod p$ does give all the information about $x$ in the range $0 ≤ x ≤ p − 2$ when $a$, $p$, and the primitive root $α$ of $p$ are given, even though computing $x$ (i.e., retrieving $x$) is computationally infeasible.

---

I know that $$r=(g^{s^{-1}h(m)}(g^{s^{-1}r})^x \mod p)\mod q$$

However, I am not sure that this equation is really in $a = αx \mod p$ form and contains all the information about $x$.

Comment: A clear question is missing at the end, could you add that? Note that this is an assignment and as such we should only give hints and / or answer the related question.

Comment: Is it meant $a=\alpha^x\bmod p$ (typeset as `a=\alpha^x\bmod p` ) where there is $a = αx \mod p$?

Comment: @fgrieu yes I meant =^ mod 